# Ubuntu button css border radius

Tags: css, ubuntu, button

I want to make a css ubuntu style button but i am having a problem with the border radius value, And i want to make the button rounded
 [as showed in the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gUlB.png) 

My HTML

```
    <button>Ubuntu button</button>
```

And my CSS

```
button {
```

```
border-radius: 4em 4em / 6em;   /* Border radios problem */
font-size: 14px;
color: #6d6d6d;
width: 133px;
height: 34px;
background: #ffffff;
display: block;
border: 0.1em solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
font-family: Ubuntu;
background-color: #f8f8f8;
outline: none;
cursor: pointer;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%,color-stop(0, rgb(255, 255, 255)),color-stop(1, rgb(240, 240, 240)));
background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(top,rgb(255, 255, 255) 0%,rgb(240, 240, 240) 100%);
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,rgb(255, 255, 255) 0%,rgb(240, 240, 240) 100%);
background-image: -ms-repeating-linear-gradient(top,rgb(255, 255, 255) 0%,rgb(240, 240, 240) 100%);
```

}
button:hover {

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgb(234, 234, 234);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgb(234, 234, 234);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgb(234, 234, 234);
```

}
button:active {

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgb(234, 234, 234);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgb(234, 234, 234);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgb(234, 234, 234);
background-color: #ededed;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%,color-stop(0, rgb(231, 231, 231)),color-stop(0.496, rgb(231, 231, 231)),color-stop(0.5, rgb(231, 231, 231)),color-stop(1, rgb(255, 255, 255)));
background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(top,rgb(231, 231, 231) 0%,rgb(231, 231, 231) 49.6%,rgb(231, 231, 231) 50%,rgb(255, 255, 255) 100%);
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,rgb(231, 231, 231) 0%,rgb(231, 231, 231) 49.6%,rgb(231, 231, 231) 50%,rgb(255, 255, 255) 100%);
background-image: -ms-repeating-linear-gradient(top,rgb(231, 231, 231) 0%,rgb(231, 231, 231) 49.6%,rgb(231, 231, 231) 50%,rgb(255, 255, 255) 100%);
```

}

### Update

It is showing clearly in this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns63G.png
the top button is css styled and the second is the ubuntu system button, as you will see, corner radius not the same

Comment: What about using `border-radius: 6px;`??

Answer (score 0):

Using px values for border-radius are more granular and reliable for border radius values than ems. Ems are relative to their parent container and could prove problematic on larger applications. I think you'll find a 4px value for border-radius more to your liking.

Comment: I have used the ems because it does not get affecting by the width or the height of the button

Comment: If you want to use ems, then you'll need to do something like .4em.

Comment: border-radius: 0.4em does not give a me the same shape